# HTML JSP code creation question

Tags: html, jsp

I have a submit button, created from  - basically when this is clicked I want a groupbox to appear below where the submit button is....any suggestions?

I've tried to get the request given of from this click however it doesn't help me.
I thought the logic would be similar to this:

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="Yes" />Yes
   <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="No" /> No
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<%
   String[] select = request.getParameterValues("group");
  /* Add code creation here */
%>
```

Any suggestions or examples you can think of?

Thanks greatly,
U.

Comment: Maybe this is just me, but I don't really iuderstand what you want to achieve... Can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: I have a 'submit' button - when it is clicked I want some HTML code to appear below the button....Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace the checkboxes by radio buttons. Right now it's possible to check both `Yes` and `No`. This makes no sense.

```html
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="Yes" /> Yes
   <input type="radio" name="group" value="No" /> No
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:if>` tag to conditionally display content depending on parameters and/or other scoped variables in [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

```xml
<c:if test="${param.group == 'Yes'}">
    <p>Write here HTML code which you'd like to show when 'Yes' is chosen.</p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${param.group == 'No'}">
    <p>Write here HTML code which you'd like to show when 'No' is chosen.</p>
</c:if>
```

Comment: I get '"test" does  not support runtime environments' from using the above code.

Comment: It's "runtime expressions" :) Please click the JSTL link in the answer and follow instructions "Help! The expression language doesn't work!". I.e. ensure that you have the right JSTL version for your target runtime and that your `web.xml` root declaration is correct. By the way, did the `<c:forEach>` work for you or not as per [my answer on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911201/java-populating-option-dropdown-list/5911308#5911308)?

Comment: Sorry mate, 'expressions' not 'environments' - spending to much time working with AMazon AWS!

Comment: And yes it works I apologise - and your previous post worked as thanks greatly!